# how to populate dynamic values in HTML email template with Letter head in a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, email-template

I am working on a Round robin record assignment on case object and I need to notify the contacts noted on the case with the new case owner details after case assignment. I have tried with workflows but it didn't worked out. So I have written a single email message class with custom html template in trigger to send an email to contact noted on case. So I am receiving the template as  HTML but my client want it with my company letterhead.

So could someone please let me know how can we populate dynamic values to a Html template with letterhead

Also I have tried to replace the values on existing HTML template with Letterhead even though I am unable to get the letterhead instead able to see a blank at the top followed by HTML message

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated...!!!

It's part of a trigger:

```
 for(case cm : [select id, CaseNumber, Subject, Priority,
                       Description,Contact_Method__c,
                       Preferred_Language__c, contact.Name,ContactEmail 
                from case
                where ID IN :Emaillist.keySet()])
    {
        system.debug('case list for email' + cm);
        for(User Un : Eulist)
        {
            if(Emaillist.get(cm.id) == un.id)
            {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage sm = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                String[] toAddresses = new String[] {cm.ContactEmail};
                sm.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                sm.setReplyTo('support@zzzz.com');
                sm.setSenderDisplayName('Support');
                sm.setSubject('Your Request was started/updated - ref' + cm.CaseNumber);
                String body = '<b>Dear'+ ' '+ cm.contact.Name +'</b>,<br>';
                body += '<p> We are pleased to inform you that the Incident you reported has <br>';
                body += 'been successfully entered into the ticketing <br>';
                body += 'system. Your assigned Reference Number is'+' '+ cm.CaseNumber +'. This<br>';
                body += 'number should be retained for reference purposes. A support <br>';
                body += 'engineer has claimed your case and will contact you as soon as possible.</p> <br>';
                body += 'Reference Number:'+' '+cm.CaseNumber +'<br>';
                body +=     'Assigned To :' +' '+  Un.Name +'<br>';
                body +=    'Mail Address :' +' '+ Un.Email +'<br>';
                body +=       'Telephone :' +' '+ Un.Phone +'<br>';
                body +=          'Subject:' + ' '+cm.Subject +'<br>';
                body +=         'Priority:' + ' '+cm.Priority +'<br> ';
                body +=   'Contact Method:' +' '+ cm.Contact_Method__c +'<br>';
                body +='Preferred Language:'+' '+cm.Preferred_Language__c +'<br>';
                body +=      'Description:' +' '+cm.Description+'<br>';
                sm.setHtmlBody(body);  
                FEmaillist.add(sm);
           }
        }
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(FEmaillist);
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: contacts receiving the email as plain text template even though I have used setHtmlBody and also my client wants this template to look like HTML with my company letterhead. So  I am unable to merge both HTML and Letter head by passing the dynamic user values to it.